# Water simulation using shaders in WPF

Tags: wpf, simulation, shader

I am searching for a way to implement a water effect for in WPF like the one demonstrated on [Lee Whitney's blog](http://lee.hdgreetings.com/2010/09/multi-touch-water-effects-in-wpf-and-silverlight.html). This is for a full screen application so it should rely on shaders in order to utilize the GPU.

So far I have found the following methods & code examples:

- [WPF](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/playing-with-shaders-creating-a-water-effect/): This example does not live up to the requirements of
  simulating drops of water, as it renders one single water ripple.
  However it performs lightning fast as it uses shaders. I tried to add
  several layers of ripples on top of each other but that did not look
  right either.
- Silverlight: This implementation offers the right features in
  terms of simulating drops and their interaction as opposed to
  rendering one ripple. However it does not perform well at all. I
  suspect the example may not use the GPU at all but calculates every
  pixel of the bitmap in software. I may  have misunderstood the code
  though as I am not strong in silverlight
- [C++]: This example is similar to the silverlight example. It
  performs a lot faster, but when scaled to a full HD size it gets too
  slow. As with silverlight it appears to me that the example is
  relying heavily on software calculations.
- Windows Surface appear to have a similar effect implement in their
  pond application. God knows how they did it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this amazing lib. http://perspectivefx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but look at this [WPF Shaders](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/playing-with-shaders-creating-a-water-effect/)

I'm learning too, and found this resource, hope this helps you.